# Long values are concatenating instead of adding

Tags: java, string, concatenation, long-integer

I have this method:

```
public NumPal next(){
   stringRev = reverseString(stringCur);
  numRev = Long.parseLong(stringRev);
  numCur = Long.parseLong(stringCur);
   numCur = (numCur + numRev);
   stringCur = Long.toString(numCur);
   NumPal n = new NumPal(stringCur);
   return n;
   }
```

When i try to add numCur and numRev it for some reason concatenates them. Are they staying as strings? I believe I'm using Long.ParseLong correctly but im not sure.

Comment: try  `(numCur+numRev)`. you should use the paranthesis if you are doing something like `System.out.println("result:" + (numCur+numRev));`

Comment: `return new NumPal(Long.parseLong(new StringBuilder(stringCur).reverse().toString()) + Long.parseLong(stringCur));`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this method isn't where your problem lies.  There's no printing code in this method, so how do you know it's concatenating?  It could be something weird in whatever code tries to print out the returned `NumPal`.  Could you share the piece of code that prints the result?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question will work a lot better if you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including one or two examples of the numbers you work on, the desired/expected result (the sum) and the observed result (the concatenation). As you can see, with what we have until now, we are struggling and guessing in the blind. Please help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the addition is overflowing long size. long size range is 2^63 to 2^63–1. If you want to addition of big numbers which cannot be accommodated in long, try the method present in this link. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-two-large-numbers/